# Probability from convolution of generating function

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have to calulate two probabilities from convolution of generating function,
$P(X_1+X_2...+X_n = k)$

$P(X_1+X_2...+X_n > k)$

Where $X_i \in (1,2...m)$(probability is 1/m)

how should i start it in case when we have digits i would make something like this:

$(\sum_{i=0}^{9}x_i)^n$

and then take argument before x^k and divide it by n^10.

Comment: $f_{X+Y} = f_X \ast f_Y$ and $F_{X+Y} = f_{X+Y} \ast \theta = f_X \ast f_Y \ast \theta$ where $\theta(x) = 1$ for $x \ge 0$ and $f_X$ is the pdf of $X$

Comment: So $f_x = 1/m$ when x>0 and 0 o.w. and f_y would look the same then i need to make convolution of it and this will be solution ?